# Orient DB replication between Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, replication, orientdb

Is it possible to replicate OrientDB databases between Linux and Windows?

I am using Orient DB 2.1.11. I set up a Replication by the instructions here: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Setup-a-distributed-database.html. The replication was working between two local windows DB instances, but if I try to replicate a Linux DB instance to Windows with the original **default-distributed-db-config.json** settings, I receive the following error on Windows side:

> Uncompressing file luceneIndexes/TABLE_NAME.INDEX_NAME/write.lock...
>   OHazelcastPlugin]{db=DB_NAME} [Slave] error on copying database
>   'DB_NAME' on local server

Even if autoDeploy is false in the distributed db config json file, and I copied the database manually before replication.

Btw: On Linux this WARNING is preceeding the error:

> 2016-08-09 15:16:33:873 WARNI [Jenkins] added new node id=Member
>   [192.168.10.98]:2434 name=ext:b04653c1-6b97-4be3-9acc-1316f6757706
>   [OHazelcastPlugin][192.168.10.73]:2434 [TestReplica] [3.5.3] While
>   waiting finalize join calls... java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:
>   Call Invocation{ serviceName='hz:core:clusterService',
>   op=FinalizeJoinOperation{postJoinOp=PostJoinOperation{operations=[com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.operations.PostJoinRegistrationOperation{serviceName='null',
>   partitionId=-1, callId=0, invocationTime=-1, waitTimeout=-1,
>   callTimeout=9223372036854775807},
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.proxyservice.impl.operations.PostJoinProxyOperation{serviceName='null',
>   partitionId=-1, callId=0, invocationTime=-1, waitTimeout=-1,
>   callTimeout=9223372036854775807},
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PostJoinMapOperation{serviceName='null',
>   partitionId=-1, callId=0, invocationTime=-1, waitTimeout=-1,
>   callTimeout=9223372036854775807}]}} MemberInfoUpdateOperation {
>   MemberInfo{address=Address[192.168.10.73]:2434}
>   MemberInfo{address=Address[192.168.10.98]:2434} }, partitionId=-1,
>   replicaIndex=0, tryCount=100, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1,
>   callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.10.98]:2434,
>   backupsExpected=0, backupsCompleted=0} encountered a timeout  at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponse(InvocationFuture.java:366)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponseOrThrowException(InvocationFuture.java:334)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:225)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.executeWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:294)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.waitWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:278)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.util.FutureUtil.waitWithDeadline(FutureUtil.java:252)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.ClusterServiceImpl.startJoin(ClusterServiceImpl.java:1024)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.ClusterServiceImpl.handleJoinRequest(ClusterServiceImpl.java:706)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.operations.JoinRequestOperation.run(JoinRequestOperation.java:40)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:315)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processPacket(OperationThread.java:142)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:115)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.doRun(OperationThread.java:101)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:76)

Comment: Could you try replication using 2.2.6 version?  Starting from v2.2, OrientDB uses internal binary protocol for replication and not Hazelcast queues anymore. Source: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Architecture.html

Comment: With version 2.2.6 the replication seems to be working if I copy the initial databases to both servers.
I also tried to let replication copy missing databases to the other instances (autodeploy: true) but it never succeeded.